# how to run foreach in synchronous way in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise

I am running email alert sending job in nodejs, due to asyncronous, hits are too many. Even elastic search throwing timeout exception.

Along with node i am using Q promise.

Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Post your code please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It really depends upon your code and your async operation.  Show us your code and we can show you how to fix it!

Answer (score -1):

If you can use new Node, google how to use async/await, then you can for-cycle all requests and await them.

If you cant, you can do it recursively:

```
function processAllOneByOne(fns, i){
  if (i >= fns.length)  { return Promise.resolve({done:true}) }
  fns[i]().then(() => processAll(fns, i+1));
}
```

And call it with

```
processAllOneByOne(fns, 0)
```

Please note that once you create promise you CANT handle how it is executed "inside". So you need to have `fns` which is array of function, calling that function creates and return Promise you want to wait to finish.

So push there something like `fns.push(() => sendAlert(some, paramaters))`, where sendAlert is creating the Promise you need.